# The best way to target DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, coffeescript

I'm a front-end developer, and I'm worried about the best way to target my DOM.

Let's imagine a tiny form to create a new zombie :

```
<h1>Add a new zombie</h1>
<form id="create-zombie">
  <input id="zombie" type="text" name="zombie" />
  <input id="lvl" type="text" name="lvl" />
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

...and if I want to get the values of `zombie` and `lvl`, I will code something like this:

```
class Zombie_Add extends Controller 

  # Dom References
  el: 
    'form': '#create-zombie'
    'zombie': '#zombie'
    'lvl': '#lvl'

  run: ->

    @on 'submit', @el.form, @validate

  validate: (e) =>

    e.preventDefault()

    zombie = $(@el.zombie).val()
    lvl = $(@el.lvl).val()

module.exports = Zombie_Add
```

That's "ok" and it does the job, but I have some problems with that "structure" :

1. If somebody touches the DOM and removes an ID, I'm just fucked, it breaks my code (Captain Obvious spotted !)
2. For more complicated selectors, it's just a mess (I'm thinking about some stuff like that `[name^="dummy-"] input:first`). I guess it's easy to imagine how shitty the names of `el` are.

Anyway, what I want to learn today is what's the best way to target the DOM from JS. Is it better to use IDs, `class` values or, `data-*` attributes? How we can prettify a selector with plain English, etc...

Comment: it depends. I usually try to avoid needing to target dom elements all together by using templating/rendering, meaning i would only need to target one element, the one that the view would need to be inserted into.

Comment: I'm not speaking about a Single Page Application here ^^

Comment: single page applications aren't the only ones that benefit from having view-based rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If somebody touches the DOM and removes an ID, I'm just ****ed, it
>   breaks my code (Captain Obvious spotted !)

The best way to target a single, unique element in the DOM is with an ID like you are doing with `zombie` and `lvl`.  It is both fast to execute and simple to code.

It is a given that if someone messes with the id values in your HTML, that will break your Javascript.  That's just the way it is.  Anyone messing with your HTML has to be smart enough to know that an ID value is there for a reason so if they want to change that or remove it, then it is their responsibility to find someone who can make corresponding changes in the Javascript.  That's just the way it is.

> For more complicated selectors, it's just a mess (I'm thinking about
>   some stuff like that [name^="dummy-"] input:first). I guess it's easy
>   to imagine how ****ty the names of el are.

The same goes for more complicated selectors.  Like it or not, a modern web page is a melding of server-side stuff, presentation HTML and Javascript.  The three have to work together to deliver the final solution.  While you strive to avoid unnecessary dependencies with good design techniques and practices, you cannot avoid all dependencies, nor would even trying to avoid all possible dependencies be an efficient way to develop.

### Example

There are coding practices that can make your code less sensitive to edits to the HTML and I consider those to be desirable practices.   For example, consider this HTML snippet:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerBorder">
        <div class="actions>
            <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>
        </div>
        <div class="contentContainer">
            <div class="content">
            ... content here
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="header">
    ... more of these repeated
</div>
```

And you want to have code that, when you click on the Hide link, it will hide the content.

If you code that like this:

```
$(".header .actions .hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().children().first().hide();
});
```

Then, you have embedded in your Javascript some extremely detailed knowledge of the HTML structure in the area of your button and content and pretty much any structural change to that HTML (even just adding one more level of div to help with some layout) will break the Javascript.  This is bad.

Instead, you could write this:

```
$(".header .actions .hide").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".header").find(".content").hide();
});
```

This depends only upon one HTML structural concept - that the `.content` that corresponds to the `.hide` button is somewhere in the common `.header` parent element.  The entire structure within that `.header` parent can be changed and this code will not break.  This is robust code that tries to be as independent of the details of the HTML structure as possible.

> Anyway, what I want to learn today is what's the best way to target
>   the DOM from JS. Is it better to use IDs, class values or, data-*
>   attributes? How we can prettify a selector with plain English, etc...

It's best to use IDs to target elements for which there is only one unique element in the page.

It's best to use class names to target elements for which there can be more than one element in the page and you can combine that with other parts of a selector if you want to target only a specific item with a class name.

data attributes can be used in selectors, but that isn't really their primary purpose.  I can't think of any reason why it would be better to use a data attribute instead of a class name.  I use data attributes for storing actual data on an object that will be used by scripts.  This tends to allow the code to be more generic and let the content describe itself.

When you talk about classes getting removed to change the state of the element, that is a legitimate use of a class, but it would just be a bad design decision to use the same class for selecting an element as for add/removing state.  Use different class names for those two purposes.  For example, you could have a class name called "selected" that indicates a selection state, but you would only use that in a selector if you wanted just the selected objects.  If you wanted all line items in a table, you wouldn't use ".selected", you'd create a more descriptive class name for that object such as "lineitem".  Remember, you can have multiple class names on an object so you can use different class names on the same object for different purposes.

You seem to be searching for some magic bullet here that prevents changes in the HTML from affecting Javascript in any way.  That simply does not exist.  Selecting a DOM element or finding a DOM element relative to something that was clicked will rely on some inherent knowledge of how the HTML is structured or tagged.  What is important is that you minimize that dependence to only what is required and that anyone messing with the HTML has an understanding of how to best change things and not break the Javascript or discusses changes with someone who knows the Javascript.  If you're using different skills/people on different portions of the project, they have to coordinate their efforts in order to not break things or be aware of what dependencies there are with the other parts of the system.  That's just the way it is.  There is no magic answer here that removes all dependencies between HTML and Javascript.  Smart designs have smaller and more obvious dependencies.  Poor designs have large and often hidden depedencies.

Your question about "plain English" isn't particularly clear to me.  It seems obvious to use descriptive ID names, class names or attribute names that make it as obvious to the reader what that particular name is being used for.   I'm not sure what you were looking for beyond that.

Comment: That's make sense but it's completely destroyed by an another bad practice : select classes (they change often, you can remove a class for the current class "state" of the element, etc ...). If I use IDs in your example, it will break too because by definition an ID is unique. So that's my question from the start, how I can target better the DOM (using data-x attributes ?)

Comment: @JeremieGes - I added some more to the end of my answer based on your last comment.  You seem to be looking for a magic bullet here - there is none.  You use good design practices to lessen dependencies between HTML and JS and make them more obvious.  There is no such thing as eliminating dependencies.

Comment: That's a perfect answer and you got what i wanted to say. So my conclusion is maybe to prefix the classes in that way ".js-example" to catch the attention of an another developer on the project. It was a pleasure to be helped by you ;)